# Can reindeers change into unicorns?

Tags: feature-request, winter-bash-2014, winter-bash-2015

[The winter bash page](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/) is pretty cool!

However, there is a reindeer:

[image]

Now while I have nothing against reindeers, unicorns are better.

How about this:

[image]

Now I'm not the best unicorn drawer, but something along those lines would be nice.

Maybe not for 2014, but (if it happens) 2015 would be nice.

Comment: Why would they go through the trouble of making this change now?  Maybe request that this be implement in Winter Bash 2015 (if there is one).

Comment: It will force unemployment among reindeers, their small reindeers child can die of hunger and ask this to Santa clause first, he is the one who selected reindeers over unicorn, dragon and pokemons too :D

Comment: I fear the site is de-unicornifing itself. 2012 had the unicorn easter egg, 2013 the unicorn hat, 2014 nothing at all. Do we like this? no. ;_;

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Reindeers cannot change into Unicorns any more than Santa can become the Easter Bunny.

They are companions, both different facets of the same magical prism and they need each other :)

That said, Unicorns are probably more qualified for the job but since they are also gracious they usually let the Reindeer pull the sleigh...usually

[image]